# saving date to RMS in Java ME

Tags: java, date, java-me, rms

I would like to save a Date object into an RMS in Java ME. The way I would like to do it is by converting the date first to some String/int/any primitive data type value that the RMS can save. I then would like to read this data back and create a Date object from it. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.getTime()`, which returns a `long`. You can reverse the process by using the `new Date(long)` constructor.